# Stop loop in typewriting effect using JS

Tags: javascript

I found this typewriting effect on Codepen, which works great, however, I'm trying to stop the loop so the typewriting effect only loads once and no more. I tried asking the author but no answer. Can you point me in the right direction? Here's the link to the original https://codepen.io/Tbgse/pen/dYaJyJ

```
// function([string1, string2],target id,[color1,color2])
consoleText(['Divi Notes.', 'Divi Tips and Tricks', 'Made with Love.'], 'text', ['#BD6983', 'tomato', 'lightblue']);

function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
  if (colors === undefined) colors = ['#fff'];
  var visible = true;
  var con = document.getElementById('console');
  var letterCount = 1;
  var x = 1;
  var waiting = false;
  var target = document.getElementById(id)
  target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
  window.setInterval(function() {

    if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var usedColor = colors.shift();
        colors.push(usedColor);
        var usedWord = words.shift();
        words.push(usedWord);
        x = 1;
        target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, 1000)
    } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        x = -1;
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, 1000)
    } else if (waiting === false) {
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
      letterCount += x;
    }
  }, 120)
  window.setInterval(function() {
    if (visible === true) {
      con.className = 'console-underscore hidden'
      visible = false;

    } else {
      con.className = 'console-underscore'

      visible = true;
    }
  }, 400)
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you indented the code so it was readable.

Comment: Comment out this line `words.push(usedWord);` and done

Comment: @ippi that will cause an error if you don't stop the `setInterval`

Comment: My apologies, and thanks Derek for correcting. Much appreciated. Newbie mistake, I solemnly swear to improve ;)

Comment: @Mark_M indeed it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you need the underscore at the end blinking or not so I just left it there.

Following changes are needed

1. Comment out the circular insertion into the arrays.

```
    var usedColor = colors.shift();
    //colors.push(usedColor);
    var usedWord = words.shift();
    //words.push(usedWord);
```

2. Stop interval at the the end of the array

```
  var wordsInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if(words.length == 0) {
        window.clearInterval(wordsInterval);
        return;
    }
```

Here's whole code (working link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrqmPg)

```js
    // function([string1, string2],target id,[color1,color2])    
    consoleText(['Hello World.', 'Console Text', 'Made with Love.'], 'text',['tomato','rebeccapurple','lightblue']);
    
    function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
      if (colors === undefined) colors = ['#fff'];
      var visible = true;
      var con = document.getElementById('console');
      var letterCount = 1;
      var x = 1;
      var waiting = false;
      var target = document.getElementById(id)
      target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
      var wordsInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
        if(words.length == 0) {
            window.clearInterval(wordsInterval);
            return;
        }
        
        if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
          waiting = true;
          target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            var usedColor = colors.shift();
            //colors.push(usedColor);
            var usedWord = words.shift();
            //words.push(usedWord);
            x = 1;
            target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
            letterCount += x;
            waiting = false;
          }, 1000)
        } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
          waiting = true;
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            x = -1;
            letterCount += x;
            waiting = false;
          }, 1000)
        } else if (waiting === false) {
          target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
          letterCount += x;
        }
      }, 120)
      window.setInterval(function() {
        if (visible === true) {
          con.className = 'console-underscore hidden'
          visible = false;
    
        } else {
          con.className = 'console-underscore'
    
          visible = true;
        }
      }, 400)
    }
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khula:700);
body {
  background: #111;
}
.hidden {
  opacity:0;
}
.console-container {
 
  font-family:Khula;
  font-size:4em;
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  width:600px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
.console-underscore {
   display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top:-0.14em;
  left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='console-container' id='console-container'><span id='text'></span><div class='console-underscore' id='console'>&#95;</div></div>
```

**Edit: Without erasure** (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKxrvM)

```js
// function([string1, string2],target id,[color1,color2])    
consoleText(['Hello World.', 'Console Text.', 'Made with Love.'], 'console-container',['tomato','rebeccapurple','lightblue']);

function consoleText(words, containerId, colors) {
  if (colors === undefined) colors = ['#fff'];
  var visible = true;
  var con = document.getElementById('console');
  var letterCount = 1;
  var x = 1;
  var waiting = false;
  var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
  var targets = [];
  
  words.forEach(() => {
      var newTarget = document.createElement('span');
      targets.unshift(newTarget);
      container.prepend(newTarget);
  });
  var target = targets.shift();
  target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
  
  var wordsInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if(words.length == 0) {
        window.clearInterval(wordsInterval);
        return;
    }
    
    if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      targets.length && (target = targets.shift());
      //target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var usedColor = colors.shift();
        //colors.push(usedColor);
        var usedWord = words.shift();
        
        
        //words.push(usedWord);
        x = 1;
        target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + (colors.length == 0? usedColor: colors[0]))
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, 1000)
    } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = false;
      letterCount = 0;
    } else if (waiting === false) {
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
      letterCount += x;
    }
  }, 120)
  window.setInterval(function() {
    if (visible === true) {
      con.className = 'console-underscore hidden'
      visible = false;

    } else {
      con.className = 'console-underscore'

      visible = true;
    }
  }, 400)
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khula:700);
body {
  background: #111;
}
.hidden {
  opacity:0;
}
.console-container {
 
  font-family:Khula;
  font-size:4em;
  text-align:center;
  height:200px;
  width:600px;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  color:white;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
}
.console-underscore {
   display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top:-0.14em;
  left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='console-container' id='console-container'><span id='text'></span><div class='console-underscore' id='console'>&#95;</div></div>
```

Comment: This throws an error because the `setInterval` function still runs one more time with an empty `words` array.

Comment: This worked as a charm! Thank you, also for the detailed explanation. I'm just starting to code also by analysing existing one that I found on the web, so this helps.

Comment: One other thig, any idea how I can stop the text from being errased? So that the typewriter text ends when the last character is revealed and the whole animation stops at this point.

Comment: You want entire text to remain on screen at the end? I mean all the words in the array?

Comment: @11thdimension Yes, that's it!

Comment: I have made some modifications to get rid of the erasure. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eKxrvM

Comment: This worked very well. Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1):

You literally need to comment out one line of code:

```
// function([string1, string2],target id,[color1,color2])
consoleText(['Divi Notes.', 'Divi Tips and Tricks', 'Made with Love.'], 'text', ['#BD6983', 'tomato', 'lightblue']);

function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
  if (colors === undefined) colors = ['#fff'];
  var visible = true;
  var con = document.getElementById('console');
  var letterCount = 1;
  var x = 1;
  var waiting = false;
  var target = document.getElementById(id)
  target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
  window.setInterval(function() {

    if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var usedColor = colors.shift();
        colors.push(usedColor);
        var usedWord = words.shift();
        //words.push(usedWord);   <--- This one right here!
        x = 1;
        target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, 1000)
    } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        x = -1;
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, 1000)
    } else if (waiting === false) {
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
      letterCount += x;
    }
  }, 120) 
}
```

The general mechanics:

```
var usedWord = words.shift();
words.push(usedWord);
```

Takes the next word to say and then adds it to the end of the array. Assuming this is what keeps track of the words, to stop it at the very end simply remove the `push`

```
var usedWord = words.shift();
//words.push(usedWord);
```

As @mark_m says you should also stop the `setInterval`:

```
// function([string1, string2],target id,[color1,color2])
consoleText(['Divi Notes.', 'Divi Tips and Tricks', 'Made with Love.'], 'text', ['#BD6983', 'tomato', 'lightblue']);

function consoleText(words, id, colors) {
  if (colors === undefined) colors = ['#fff'];
  var visible = true;
  var con = document.getElementById('console');
  var letterCount = 1;
  var x = 1;
  var waiting = false;
  var target = document.getElementById(id)
  target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
  var interval = window.setInterval(function() {

    if (letterCount === 0 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var usedColor = colors.shift();
        colors.push(usedColor);
        var usedWord = words.shift();
        //words.push(usedWord);   <--- This one right here!
        if(words.length==0) clearInterval(interval)
        x = 1;
        target.setAttribute('style', 'color:' + colors[0])
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, 1000)
    } else if (letterCount === words[0].length + 1 && waiting === false) {
      waiting = true;
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        x = -1;
        letterCount += x;
        waiting = false;
      }, 1000)
    } else if (waiting === false) {
      target.innerHTML = words[0].substring(0, letterCount)
      letterCount += x;
    }
  }, 120) 
}
```

P.S. I realise this is your first post, but this is not a coding service. Show us how you tried to fix the issue. Otherwise you are unlikely to get a real response.

Comment: This causes errors once `words` has nothing left because the interval is still running. It will fill the console with `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'words[0].length')`

Comment: @Mark_M Yeah I read your comment in the main post after I had posted this. Edited the post to fix that

Comment: @ippi huh? Literally getting no errors in my console, so not sure why you're getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

just remove `push()` into `words` array, comment the following line, it is enough to typewrite it once.

```
words.push(usedWord);
```

PS: Clear interval should be used to avoid calling the function code again.

```
  if(!words || words.length == 0){
        clearInterval(t);
        return;
    }
```

Check [Codepen for the demo](https://codepen.io/msolimans/pen/ERrLKR)

Comment: If you read the comments you will see why this throws lots and lots of errors on the console.

Comment: updated the codepen, clearing interval is good enough to handle all errors, thanks though for your comment, appreciated

Comment: @msoliman, would you know how to stop the erasing effect by chance? So once the text is loaded/typed it stays as is.

Comment: @Alex I updated the codepen `https://codepen.io/msolimans/pen/ERrLKR?editors=1111`  to have the same effect you want, please leave a comment if you still need more help